# Load iPod Touch Videos in Banshee?

Tags: 11.04, banshee, ipod

Ok, now I figured out how to sync my music from my iPod Touch with Banshee on Ubuntu 11.04 which wasn't that hard in the first place, pretty much plug and play. My question is, is there a way to copy off my movies that I have on my iPod Touch into Banshee and play them using either Banshee or say, VLC Player? I have absolutely no idea if there is a way to do this and so far my searches on Google have yielded very few results if any at that...

Any help would be greatly appreciated even if it's a simple, "Nope, can't be done..."

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done because of the security restrictions on the files.  iTunes and other movie sources have DRM or other protection enabled on those files, as such it cannot be loaded in non-iTunes systems or systems without the DRM information to unlock it.

However, non-DRM videos should still be viewable assuming you have the correct codecs (for example, freely distributed videos, such as a video rip from YouTube)